# Copy source xml and other details

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Source file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--It will contain more data, just given few here-->
<Food>
<Menu>Item1</Menu>
</Food>
```

Require output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Detail>
<SubDetail>
<Food>
<Menu>Item1</Menu>
</Food>
</SubDetail>
</Detail>
```

I would like to add the source xml(contains more than 200 lines) in between Detail and SubDetails. Could you please tell me how to write the xslt.

Comment: Please show exactly how the input looks and which corresponding output you want to create. I am afraid posting an input document with a root element named `Food` and a contradicting comment "will contain more data" is rather confusing as there can't be more than one root element in a well-formed XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stating the obvious: Instead of explicit recursive copying, you could also use `<xsl:copy-of>` command if you want to copy the selected node and all of its contents. Copying the whole input document inside `<Detail>` and `<SubDetail>` wrapper element can be done with one xsl command within one template. Your final use case is probably more complex, but the logic is the same.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Detail>
        <SubDetail>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </SubDetail>
    </Detail>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only the sample data you've given to go on, you could modify the identity template slightly to get the output you're looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Detail>
      <SubDetail>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </SubDetail>
    </Detail>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Add select="@*|node()" in your apply-templates (it will be more generic if attributes come up in the source document). You can also simplify your XSLT using match"/" instead of match="Food" and put apply-template just after element SubDetails.

Comment: @VincentBiragnet Sounds good, done.  How's that look?  I assume that was the apply-templates you referred to?

Comment: Bert, you best move it from first to second apply-templates. That is where you need it. Document root can't have attributes. Some parsers will complain if you still try to access them, that's why I advise moving the select (instead of duplicating it on the second apply-templates)..